# Proof of Theorem 4.2.1 in Herzog-Hibi, "Monomial Ideals"

Tags: commutative-algebra

The Theorem and its proof can be found [here](http://download.springer.com/static/pdf/479/chp%253A10.1007%252F978-0-85729-106-6_4.pdf?originUrl=http%3A%2F%2Flink.springer.com%2Fchapter%2F10.1007%2F978-0-85729-106-6_4&token2=exp=1463601268~acl=%2Fstatic%2Fpdf%2F479%2Fchp%25253A10.1007%25252F978-0-85729-106-6_4.pdf%3ForiginUrl%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Flink.springer.com%252Fchapter%252F10.1007%252F978-0-85729-106-6_4*~hmac=9a2c75277a47a3d28c7771c642ce81dd22fc35314d38eed303dd47a7764692b8).

Specifically, i am stuck at the fourth paragraph of the proof.
Let me give some context: Let $I$ be a graded ideal over a polynomial ring $S=K[x_1,\dots,x_n]$
over a field $K$ and consider a monomial order $>$ such that $x_1>x_2>\cdots>x_n$. Let $I$ be a graded ideal and let $\operatorname{gin}_<(I)$ be its generic initial ideal. Let $\alpha$ be an elementary upper triangular matrix such that $\alpha \left( \operatorname{gin}_<(I)_d\right) \neq \operatorname{gin}_<(I)_d$, where the subscript $d$ denotes component of degree $d$. Let $t$ be the $K$-dimension of $\operatorname{gin}_<(I)$ and let $w_1,\dots,w_t$ be a basis of monomials, and $w=w_1 \wedge \cdots \wedge w_t$. Finally, define $\alpha(w) = \alpha(w_1)\wedge \cdots \wedge \alpha(w_t)$. Then the claim that i can not see why is true, is the following:

**Claim:** There is an exterior monomial $u$ in the support of $\alpha(w)$, such that $u> w$.

**Question:** How do we see that?